# Output an xml file from an sql database via php

Tags: php, sql, xml

I need help to generate a simple xml file of youtube id's from my sql database via php.

DESIRED OUTPUT

```xml
<videos>
<youtube media="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hTiRnqnvDs" autoplay="true"></youtube>
<youtube media="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wx0GfbC0BA" autoplay="true"></youtube>
<youtube media="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERGrSQoY5fs" autoplay="true"></youtube>
</videos>
```

MY OUTPUT

```xml
<videos>
    <youtube media="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=![CDATA[$value]]" autoplay="true"></youtube>
    <youtube media="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=![CDATA[$value]]" autoplay="true"></youtube>
    <youtube media="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=![CDATA[$value]]" autoplay="true"></youtube>
</videos>
```

This is the output I get from a database query

```
SELECT `key`,`value` FROM `jr_jryoutube_item_key` WHERE `key` = "youtube_id"
```

Result:

```
----------  -----------
key            value
----------  -----------
youtube_id  3VVAzFlmeWc
youtube_id  Rr9SfJwctRg
youtube_id  ocOZLHyOSZw
youtube_id  n-rQDYNOCyA
youtube_id  VaQlSnII-Hc
```

Below is my attempt.It's generating an xml file but it's not reading the youtube id's.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
     //database configuration
$_conf['jrCore_db_host'] = 'localhost';
$_conf['jrCore_db_port'] = '3306';
$_conf['jrCore_db_name'] = 'xxxxxx';
$_conf['jrCore_db_user'] = 'xxxxxx';
$_conf['jrCore_db_pass'] = 'xxxxxx';

       //connect to host
$con = mysqli_connect($_conf['jrCore_db_host'],$_conf['jrCore_db_user'],$_conf['jrCore_db_pass']);

      // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

      // select database

mysqli_select_db($con,$_conf['jrCore_db_name']);

echo "Connected successfully";

$myFile = "videos.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'wb') or die("can't open file");
$xml_txt .= '<videos>';

    // $query is an array with your values
$query = "SELECT `key`,`value` FROM `jr_jryoutube_item_key` WHERE `key` = 'youtube_id'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($result_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

   {

      //loop through each key,value pair in row
      foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
        {          
         //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
         $xml_txt .= '<youtube media="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=![CDATA[$value]]" autoplay="true">';
         $xml_txt .= '</youtube>';  

         }

     }
}

$xml_txt .= '</videos>';
fwrite($fh, $xml_txt);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: my apologies.The autoplay is hard coded and does not change.It's set to true.I made a mistake in the question(see edited version)....thanks

Comment: why was my question downvoted?

Comment: Side note: I believe the *real* reason your `$value` isn't being evaluated is due to the fact that you're using `'` and not `"` when  appending the `<youtube>` tag to `$xml_txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use fwrite for xml files, there are more convenient methods available. For example, you can use simple_xml:

```
$videoxml = new SimpleXMLElement("<videos></videos>");
```

you are running a foreach loop in a while loop, which is wrong. Simply run the while loop and pick the value from the resultset:

```
$url   = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $result_array['value'];
$video = $videoxml->addChild('youtube');
$video->{0} = $url;
$video->addAttribute('autoplay', 'true');
```

I hope I've interpreted your code right, but as far as I see there is no reason to pick "key" from DB as you don't use it.

The code with the loops should look something like that:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<videos></videos>");

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $url   = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $row['value'];
    $video = $xml->addChild('youtube');
    $video->{0} = $url;
    $video->addAttribute('autoplay', 'true');
}

$xml->saveXML('/path/to/file.xml')
```

Please notice that I have given the value to the tag directly, not using two attributes and no content for the tag.

Comment: It looks like this can work.However I got an error                 Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/youtube.php on line 45

Comment: You copied $videoxml = new SimpleXMLElement("<videos></videos>"); too? @user3011222

Comment: I forgot that....But after correcting that mistake,everything is working perfectly....Bravo!...Excellent!...Thanks

Comment: Can I make the script dynamic?...make it update any new youtube id from the database...

Comment: Well, if you just let it run like it is it will always overwrite the old file, so it is kind of dynamic right now

Comment: I just noticed an error in the output.                             <youtube autoplay="true">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VVAzFlmeWc</youtube>

Comment: Yes, I wrote that it will fill the actual tag, not the attribute, if you want to change that, simply change it to ...->addChild('youtube',''); and add $video->addAttribute('media','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$result_array['value']);